# How do you write a template for this code?

Tags: c++, templates, vector

So this is my C++ hw, and for now the only errors I got are those:

liux1780_9B.cpp:10:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::vector’ without an argument list
 vector bubblesort(vector );
 ^

liux1780_9B.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

liux1780_9B.cpp:68:8: error: missing template arguments before ‘bubblesort’
 vector bubblesort(vectoritem);
        ^

liux1780_9B.cpp:68:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘bubblesort’

liux1780_9B.cpp: At global scope:

liux1780_9B.cpp:76:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘std::vector’ 
without an argument list
 vector bubblesort(vectoritem) {
 ^
Compilation failed.

And here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector bubblesort(vector<item>);

class item
{
    private:
        int numItem;
        string itemName;
    public:
        item(int numItem, string itemName)
        {
            this->numItem = numItem;
            this->itemName = itemName;
        }
        int getnumItem()
        {
            return numItem;
        }
        string getitemName()
        {
            return itemName;
        }

        bool operator<(item r) 
        {
            return this->getnumItem() < r.getnumItem();
        }
};


int main()
{
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str());
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(fileName.c_str());
    if (fout.fail())
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    int count;
    string name;
    vector<item> list;

    while (fin >> name)
    {
        fin >> count;   
        list.push_back(item(count, name));
    }

vector bubblesort(vector<item>);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

vector bubblesort(vector<item>) {
    int temp;
    bool finished = false;
    while (!finished)    {
    finished = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < item.size()-1; i++) {
      if (item[i] > item[i+1]) {
         temp = item[i];
         item[i] = item[i+1];
         item[i+1] = temp;
         finished=false;
          }
        }
     }
    return item; 
}
```

Comment: Consider using `std::swap` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to forward declare your `item` class before using it as the template argument of `vector`.

```
class item;
```

Then you need to ensure the return `vector` also has a type

```
vector<item> bubblesort(vector<item>);
```

Also in your function itself you need to give the argument variable a name and use that variable

```
vector<item> bubblesort(vector<item> items)
{
    \\ do stuff with items
}
```

You should also consider passing the initial vector as a `const` reference to avoid a copy, since you are going to return a new vector anyway. Or pass in a non-`const` reference to the vector and modify it in-place.

Comment: Passing by value is the right thing to do here. The function transforms the copy its given and returns that. Making a new one and copying the parameter is extra work and doesn't allow for moves. Of course the non-const reference option is still good if in-place modification is desired.